# is it possible to overload wcout << operator to substitute it with WriteConsoleW?

Tags: c++, winapi, console, operator-overloading, widechar

The thing is that MinGW compiled program has problems with printing non-ascii chars on console through wcout, the output may show characters from different codepage or be completely blank. But winapi `WriteConsoleW` works perfectly. So I ask if there is a possibility to change behavior of << operator so it would aways invoke winapi method.

(I didn't find any examples how to do it and I'm new to c++, there is lot of examples how to overload an object but not how to do it with string or wide char array.)

Comment: Yes, I think streambuf is the right place to do this.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a suitable stream buffer sending characters wherever you need to send them. You can use `rdbuf()` to set the stream buffer used by `std::wcout`. I don't think I have provided an example using `wchar_t` as character type in the past but it would work just as the plenty examples for `char`.